# ICollection vs ICollection<T>- Ambiguity between ICollection<T>.Count and ICollection.Count

Tags: c#, generics, icollection

Note: This is similar, but not quite the same as [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544480/icollection-icollectiont-ambiguity-problem)

I've implemented an `IBusinessCollection` interface. It dervies from both `ICollection<T>`, and the old-busted non-generic `ICollection`. I'd prefer to just dump the old busted `ICollection`, but I'm using WPF databinding with a CollectionView which wants me to implement the old-busted non-generic `IList` :-(

Anyway, the interfaces look like this:

```
public interface IBusinessCollection<T> : ICollection<T>, ICollection
{ }

public interface ICollection<T>
{ int Count { get; } }

public interface ICollection
{ int Count { get; } }
```

Due to using Dependency Injection, I'm passing around objects of type `IBusinessCollection<T>` using their interfaces, *not* by concrete types, so I have something like this:

```
internal class AnonymousCollection : IBusinessCollection<string>
{ 
    public int Count { get { return 5; } }
}

public class Factory
{
    public static IBusinessCollection<string> Get()
    { return new AnonymousCollection(); }
}
```

When I try and call this code, I get an error, as follows:

```
var counter = Factory.Get();
counter.Count; // Won't compile
// Ambiguity between 'ICollection<string>.Count' and 'ICollection.Count'
```

There are 3 ways to make this compile, but all of them are ugly.

1. Cast the class to it's concrete implementation (which I may not know)
2. Cast the class explicitly to `ICollection`
3. Cast the class explicitly to `ICollection<T>`

Is there a fourth option which doesn't require me to cast things at all? I can make whatever changes I need to `IBusinessCollection<T>`

Comment: Why not implement both interfaces explicitly, and the common ones directly? It still makes it possible "to program against an interface, not against an implementation" from the outside.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This appears to solve the issues in my quick tests.

```
public interface IBusinessCollection<T> : ICollection<T>, ICollection
{
    new int Count { get;  }
}
```

Comment: PS. Didn't know you could do 'new' in interfaces. That's nice :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
ICollection<string> counter = Factory.Get();
counter.Count; // No longer ambiguous
```

Comment: I don't think this actually solves the problem.  In my sample code, I get the ambiguity error with `var` or the explicit `IBusinessCollection<string>` type.

Comment: The question requested a fourth option.  He already knew about this possibility.

Comment: I still get the ambiguity err.

Comment: I've juggled this around in edits, and finally settled on `ICollection<string>` because I don't know if using `IBusinessCollection<string>` actually resolves the conflict or not (probably not). If you actually need an `IBusinessCollection<string>` type for your variable, then you may need to cast.

Comment: @John: This is *not* a cast, it's not even a conversion, it's a simple assignment to a lower level type. It also avoids using the concrete type, so I don't see how this isn't a different solution. @bobby: You're right, see my last comment and edits fixing up the misleading info.

Comment: @Matthew: In #1, he clearly indicates that he may not know the right type to use. So, he wouldn't be able to specify "ICollection<string>" as the variable type.

Comment: @John: of course he can. He knows he's getting an `IBusinessObject<string>`. This interface implements `ICollection<string>`. Contrary to popular believe `var` is **not** variant! It's a static type that is in this case being resolved at compile time to `IBusinessCollection<string>`, which has two properties defined in two seperate subinterfaces that have the same name. Using one or the other if possible removes the ambiguity.

Comment: I don't want to cast it or have to explicitly state the type. I just want to use var and have clean code. As far as that goes, ICollection<string> counter is the same as var counter = (ICollection<string>), and doesn't solve the issue